# Unable to set "Team" to "None" in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, code-signing

I'm exactly using Xcode 6.3.2, and I was given a project where the "Team" in its target was set to a certain one, and I see this setting as "Unknown" (since I don't have an account associated to this team). I'm trying to set this to "None" but Xcode doesn't allow me to do that. I don't receive any warning when selecting "None" from the drop-down list, it simply ignores the selection and returns to the "Unknown" value.

How could I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If its possible for you then remove all your added account from the Accounts tab in Xcode preferences.

Then after set the `Code Signing Identity` & `Provisional Profile` to Automatic in build setting.

Then I think you will be able to set None in Xcode. Hope this works.

Comment: It doesn't work. Did anyone find a way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the way. At first, I did remove all accounts. Then added valid apple-id, and joined developers program. After that I'm able to select my valid Team. And only after setting valid team I could change the Team to None.

Comment: No need to remove accounts. Just select a valid team and than change team to none.